# python mysql execute is hanging

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using python to control my mysql Database for a automatic garden watering project.

Im using MySQLdb and everything was working fine, but lately I came across an error.

```
def changeSize(self, size, table):
    command = "select * from Feuchtigkeitswerte order by ID desc limit 1"
    self._curs.execute(command)
    lastRow = self._curs.fetchone()
    if len(lastRow)-3 < size:
        command = "alter table Feuchtigkeitswerte "
        for x in range(len(lastRow)-2, size):
            command += "add column Ort_{:d} NUMERIC, ".format(x)
        command += "add column Ort_{:d} NUMERIC".format(size)
        print command
    if len(lastRow)-3 > size:
        command = "alter table Feuchtigkeitswerte "
        for x in range(size+1,len(lastRow)-3):
            command += "drop Ort_{:d}, ".format(x)
        command += "drop Ort_{:d}".format(len(lastRow)-3)
        print command
    self._curs.execute("SET autocommit=1");
    self._curs.execute(command)
    print("Checkpoint");
    self._curs.execute("SET autocommit=0");
```

When I execute this function and try to change the amounts columns I get this back:

```
Start
FWerte erhalten: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
alter table Feuchtigkeitswerte add column Ort_4 NUMERIC, add column Ort_5 NUMERIC, add column Ort_6 NUMERIC
```

I added the line

```
print("Checkpoint")
```

to check, wether he went past the

```
self._curs.execute(command)
```

line, but he obviously didn't pass. I tried severel things like autocommit but it didn't work, can someone help me?

Comment: I forgot to add, that if i copy the command the function is printing and paste it in the mysql console, it doesn't hang at all and it doesn't give any errors back

Comment: It's not clear to me what your actual issue is. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: An `ALTER TABLE` can take long, very long. Instead of adding more columns, you should find a database schema that does not require constant table changes.

Comment: So my problem is, that the programm is hanging at this point, it did't pass this point where it does `self._curs.execute(command)`

and @KlausD. : I tried it in the mysql console and it didn't take so long...